# Non-EU married to Dutch citizen, EU Free Movement Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

My wife (non-EU) and I (Dutch) are married in the Netherlands. My wife still lives in Asia and I live in the Netherlands. We also have a baby together who has a Dutch passport but is living with her in Asia.

I am wondering if she is eligible for a Schengen visa based on EU freedom of movement if she travels to a Belgium airport and enters the EU from there. I will be traveling with her but our main stay will be in the Netherlands.

Comment: @Giorgio the facts here are rather different, since in the other question the couple reside in the EU, and, more importantly, they are not asking about visiting the EU citizen's country of citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Netherlands is your wife's main destination, she must apply to the Netherlands for her visa.  Because you are a Dutch citizen in the Netherlands, your wife's visa application would normally fall under Dutch law rather than the EU free movement regime.  Therefore, she should be required to pay the visa fee for her Schengen visa.